# Laravel Session works on Chrome, Not on Iphone

Tags: php, laravel, session, mobile-safari

I have created a system where users can search for payment solutions for their business here: http://104.236.45.72/

When you click an answer for a question, you'll notice that as you click through on chrome, you get a list at the top of previously answered questions.

When you view this same thing on your mobile device, you'll notice that the questions as the top only show ONE. It's like the session is not persisting on mobile. I have no idea why and I've tried changing the session driver from database to file and tried replacing all of the "$request->session->" references with "Session::", which leads to the same thing, it working on desktop and only showing one previous answer on mobile.

Here is the function being called when you answer a question on the fontend.

```
public function questions(Request $request, $id, $parentId, $question)
{

    //Get the industry...
    $data['industry'] = Industries::find($id);

    //Get the parent level question and one child...
    $data['parentQuestion'] = Questions::where('parentId', $parentId)->where('industryId', $id)->get();


    if(count($data['parentQuestion']) > 0) {
        foreach($data['parentQuestion'] as $pq) {

            if($pq->parentId != 0) {

                //How many steps are currently in the array?
                if ($request->session()->has('lastSteps')) {
                    $hasLastSteps = TRUE;    
                }else {
                    $hasLastSteps = FALSE;
                }

                $stepCount = 1;

                if($hasLastSteps == TRUE) {
                    $stepCount += count(Session('lastSteps'));
                }

                //Get the last steps ready...
                $lsQuestion = Questions::find($question);

                $lsAnswer = Questions::find($parentId);
                $lsQ = array(
                    'unique' => uniqid(),
                    'questionId' => $question,
                    'question' => $lsQuestion->question,
                    'answer' => $lsAnswer->question,
                    'url' => '/'.$request->path(),
                    'stepCount' => $stepCount
                );

                $dup = 0;

                //see if the session has a lastSteps array...
                if ($hasLastSteps == TRUE) {
                    $temp = Session('lastSteps');
                    foreach($temp as $t) {
                        if($t['questionId'] == $question) {
                            $dup = 1;
                        }
                    }
                }

                //No duplicates exist, go ahead and add it to the session!
                if($dup === 0) {
                    $request->session()->push('lastSteps', $lsQ);
                }
            }

            //Grab its children...
            if($pq->type === 'question') {
                $data['children'] = Questions::where('industryId', $id)->where('parentId', $pq->id)->get();
            }else {
                //its an endpoint / answer!
            }
        }
    }

    //see if the session has a follow up array...
    if ($request->session()->has('followUp')) {
        $data['followUp'] = Session('followUp');
    }else {
        $data['followUp'] = array();
    }

    //see if the session has a lastSteps array...
    if ($request->session()->has('lastSteps')) {
        $data['lastSteps'] = Session('lastSteps');
    }else {
        $data['lastSteps'] = array();
    }

    return view('frontend.questions', $data);

}
```

Comment: Works fine for me on PC/Android, so I would hazard to say it's unrelated to your code, or system. I'm guessing it's being caused by the iPhone your using. It's possible the phone doesn't have cookies enabled, which is what Laravel uses to store the session id.

Comment: I have cookies enabled, but on every iOS device i try, the session just restarts every time that I choose an answer.